how can i add an horizontal scrollbar in my shadcn table component
<DataTableToolbar
        table={table}
        filterBy={filterBy}
        placeholder={filterPlaceholder}
        status={status}
        button={filterActionButton}
        back={back}
      />
      <div className={cn(tableShellClassName)}>
        {isPending ? (
          <TableSkeletonMemoized tableShellClassName="px-0" />
        ) : (
          <div
            className={cn(
              "!overflow-scroll rounded-md border !scrollbar scrollbar-thumb-neutral-600",
              className
            )}
            key="table">
            <Table className="size-full !overflow-scroll !scrollbar scrollbar-thumb-neutral-600">
              <TableHeader>
                {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
                  <TableRow key={headerGroup.id}>
                    {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => (
                      <TableHead key={header.id} colSpan={header.colSpan}>
                        {!header.isPlaceholder && (
                          <span
                            style={{
                              whiteSpace: "nowrap",
                              overflow: "hidden",
                              textOverflow: "ellipsis",
                              fontSize: "1rem",
                            }}>
                            {flexRender(header.column.columnDef.header, header?.getContext())}
                          </span>
                        )}
                      </TableHead>
                    ))}
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
              </TableHeader>
              <TableBody className="!overflow-scroll !scrollbar scrollbar-thumb-neutral-600">
                {!noRecordsFound ? (
                  table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => {
                    return (
                      <TableRow
                        key={row.id}
                        data-state={row.getIsSelected() && "selected"}
                        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions
                        onClick={() => handleDataRecordClick(row)}>
                        {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => {
                          return (
                            <TableCell key={cell.id} className="px-2 hover:cursor-pointer">
                              <span
                                style={{
                                  whiteSpace: "nowrap",
                                  overflow: "hidden",
                                  textOverflow: "ellipsis",
                                }}>
                                {flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}
                              </span>
                            </TableCell>
                          );
                        })}
                      </TableRow>
                    );
                  })
                ) : (
                  <TableRow>
                    <TableCell colSpan={columns.length} className="h-40 text-center">
                      <div className="flex max-w-[calc(100dvw-2rem)] flex-col items-center justify-center py-52">
                        <Image
                          src="/illustrations/empty-table.svg"
                          className="size-44 object-contain"
                          width={320}
                          height={320}
                          alt="No records found so far."
                        />
                        <p className="text-neutral-500">No Records Found.</p>
                      </div>
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                )}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      <DataTablePagination table={table} />

This is my data-table component code. I have 7 columns and it overflows to the right. If u are using a laptop it is easy to scroll horizontally using your touch pad and if u are on a pc u can use arrow keys but i want to make it so that there is a horizontal scrollbar visible and are able to scroll.
I know i added many "overflow-scroll" classes to any possible component/HTML tags but none of them work. I can only see the vertical scrollbar visible not the horizontal one.
can someone help me with this issue. i just want a horizontal scrollbar which can be used for horizontal scrolling

I switched browsers. previously i was using arc but when i switched to chrome i chrome i could see the scrollbars. and on mac u cant see any visible scrollbars on any browser by default

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
